# ERROR: Parameter 0 has unknown type 17CameraChangeEvent?

Tags: c++, webassembly, vtk, emscripten, embind

I have been trying to call a Typescript function that I passed as a pointer into the C++ file using emscripten:: val. Thereafter, I am calling the function using the argument necessary using val.

```
struct CameraChangeEvent{
    double *position;
    double viewAngle;
    double *clippingRange;
    double *focalPoint;
    bool parallelProjection;
    double *physicalTranslation;
    double *viewUp;
    double parallelScale;
};

class Renderer {
private:
  emscripten::val vtkCameraChangeFn;
  vtkNew<vtkRenderer> renderer;

public:

  void Run(emscripten::val vtkCameraChangeFn) {
     CameraChangeEvent positionChange;
     positionChange.position = this->renderer->GetActiveCamera()a->GetPosition();
     positionChange.viewAngle = this->renderer->GetActiveCamera()->GetViewAngle();
     positionChange.clippingRange = this->renderer->GetActiveCamera()->GetClippingRange();
     positionChange.focalPoint = this->renderer->GetActiveCamera()->GetFocalPoint();
     positionChange.parallelProjection = this->renderer->GetActiveCamera()->GetParallelProjection();
     positionChange.parallelProjection = this->renderer->GetActiveCamera()->GetParallelProjection();
     positionChange.viewUp = this->renderer->GetActiveCamera()->GetViewUp();
     positionChange.parallelScale = this->renderer->GetActiveCamera()->GetParallelScale();
    this->vtkCameraChangeFn = vtkCameraChangeFn;

    this->vtkCameraChangeFn.operator()(positionChange);

  }
```

However, in the Web UI chrome debugger, I seem to be receiving the following error:
[image]

I am very new to Emscripten and C++, so I do not understand where the binding error comes from out here. I have already used Embind for the run function so that it can be used in Typescript to pass a specific Typescript function as a pointer. And of course, I am using the operator function in [val.h](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/val.h.html) for it.